# C#: порядок команд SMTP

Tags: c#, smtp

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по такому вопросу:
На мой SMTP-сервер приходят команды от клиента вот в таком порядке:

> **EHLO**
>
> MAIL FROM
>
> RCPT TO
>
> **DATA**

Но дальше - никаких команд, вплоть до таймаута.
Меня вот что смутило - если используется команда **EHLO**, то должна по идее использоваться команда **BDAT**, а не **DATA**. Верно?

Самое интересное:
на команду **DATA** я отвечаю:

> "354 Start mail input; end with .\r\n"

затем я считываю текст письма, затем пишу клиенту

> "250 OK\r\n"

**Теперь, по идее клиент должен выслать команду "QUIT",  но ее не последовало.
Я в растерянности, никаких идей больше не осталось.  Может кто сталкивался с подобным?**
Судя по литературе в сети, я делаю все верно, но, очевидно, не все..

**UPD**

Я так проверяю работу сервиса

```
var client = new SmtpClient("Leonardo-PC", 25);
var m = new MailMessage("localm@bank.lan", "+38065741545@Leonardo-PC");

m.Body = "Hello";
client.Send(m);

Console.WriteLine(">> " + i + " (1)");
```

Код висит на строчке `client.Send(m);` потом соединение обрывается по таймауту

Может я что-то неправильно делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Меня вот что смутило - если используется команда EHLO, то должна по идее использоваться команда BDAT, а не DATA. Верно?

Не верно. Клиент **может** использовать `BDAT`, но только если в ответ на `EHLO` сервер отправил клиенту `250 CHUNKING`, показывающее что сервер поддерживает расширение для chunked-передачи. Хотя может и не использовать(даже если сервер это расширение поддерживает).

> Теперь, по идее клиент должен выслать команду "QUIT", но ее не последовало

Не должен. Клиент может сколько угодно поддерживать соединение с сервером - для возможности отправки последующих сообщений. В частности, стандартный [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) посылает `QUIT` только при вызове `Dispose()`.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос  -  я написал ,как именно я проверяю работу сервиса, но даже там что-то не в порядке - код висит на строчке отправки имейла вплоть до таймаута